# cannot deploy on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I am new to coding and I am facing an error after updating routes for React. Heroku is giving an error saying that index.html is missing even though I checked and it's there. I used `create-react-app` for install and followed the Heroku guide for Node.js to get started.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

```
-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > node-js-getting-started@0.3.0 heroku-postbuild
       > npm run build
       
       
       > node-js-getting-started@0.3.0 build
       > react-scripts build
       
       Could not find a required file.
         Name: index.html
         Searched in: /tmp/build_4858e5c3/public
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - node_modules checked into source control
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Is your `index.html` in the `public/` directory after a build?

Comment: Forget _after_ a build, I'd expect this error if `public/index.html` was missing _during_ the build - it's coming from `react-scripts build`. Without a [mre] all we can suggest is you figure out where that file went.